# Is there a cross-sectional / cohort hybrid study design?

Tags: panel-data, observational-study

We are looking to evaluate non-causal relationships between two variables ascertained at different points in time. These data come from a longitudinal cohort study where other risk factors were collected at several points in time. However, for the risk factors *we* are interested in, the exposure was measured only once and the outcome several years after the fact.

In some regard it is more powerful than a cross-sectional design but less powerful than what people usually call a longitudinal, panel, or cohort design.